# How to analyze content of column value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a input file with the following content (without headers) and delimiter is tabulation:

```
Maria 1230 popb@gmail.com 1991 21 Adress 18
mama@gmail.com 3230 1992 22 Adress 19
```

I know the result columns that should be:

```
AGE ZIP EMAIL YEAR ADDRESS
```

How to place columns values by columns names like this:

```
AGE   ZIP   EMAIL            YEAR    ADDRESS
21    1230  popb@gmail.com   1991    Adress 18
22    3230  mama@gmail.com   1991    Adress 19
```

It is my first experience in Pandas

Comment: So the fields in the input file can be in any sequence? and can contain a Name (for example "Maria") which you ignore? And the ZIP could be something like 1992, which could be mistaken for a year?

Comment: Which orders of columns are possible for the input? It seems like there is more than one possible order. In case there are multipe: Which countries ZIP code are we talking about, what is the allowed range for the ZIP code? What is the year, is it a birth year? In this case you could determine which number is a birth year and which is an age by comparing it using the current year (or from whenever this dataset is). The email should be easy to recognize. Matching addresses is tricky, do they follow a certain pattern?

Comment: As ewz93 has made abundantly clear, there are a LOT of details missing in order to clean up a dataset that's as dirty as this one. I can probably be done, but we'll need a lot more than just 2 of who knows how many possibilities.

Comment: Yes, in different sequence, for year in can be between 1990 and 2000. Zip code is by standart

Comment: There is not concrete rules adress can be different, year yes it is has format YYYY. If you assume to use regex - okay, explian how to use them. I will glad to know the principle how to do that in Pandas